# C++ specialized function template alias syntax

Tags: c++

I have

```cpp
class ClassA {};
class ClassB {};

auto func_a() -> ClassA {
    return ClassA(); // example implementation for illustration. in reality can be different. does not match the form of func_b
}

auto func_b() -> ClassB {
    return ClassB(); // example implementation for illustration. in reality can be different. does not match the form of func_a
}
```

I want to be able to use the syntax

```cpp
func<ClassA>() // instead of func_a()
func<ClassB>() // instead of func_b()
```

(this is as part of a bigger template)

but I don't know how to implement this template specialization for the function alias.
Help? What is the syntax for this?

[Edit] The answers posted so far do not answer my question, so I'll edit my question to be more clear.

The actual definition of func_a and func_b is more complex than just "return Type();". Also they cannot be touched. So consider them to be

```
auto func_a() -> ClassA {
    // unknown implementation. returns ClassA somehow
}
auto func_b() -> ClassB {
    // unknown implementation. returns ClassB somehow
}
```

I cannot template the contents of func_a or func_b. I need the template for func<ClassA|ClassB> to be specialized for each one of the two and be able to select the correct one to call

Comment: Based on your edit, I think @Jarod42 has the solution you are looking for

Comment: @CoryKramer I think you're right, trying it right now; but I'm surprised this would be the answer, because of using the "if" statement. Does this incur any runtime cost over calling the specialized functions directly, or does it get removed in compile time?

Comment: @AqoCyrale `constexpr` is a compile-time construct. You can basically think of it as for each template instantiation only one of those branches even exist at runtime, and the other may be optimized away.

Comment: thanks for explaining. upvoting Jarod's solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might do something like (c++17):

```cpp
template <typename T>
auto func()
{
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, ClassA>) {
        return func_a();
    } else {
        return func_b();
    }
}
```

Alternative for pre-C++17 is tag dispatching (which allows customization point):

```cpp
// Utility class to allow to "pass" Type.
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

// Possibly in namespace details
auto func(Tag<ClassA>) { return func_a(); }
auto func(Tag<ClassB>) { return func_b(); }

template <typename T>
auto func() { return func(Tag<T>{}); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A 
{
public:
    void hi()
    {
        std::cout << "hi\n";
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    void boo()
    {
        std::cout << "boo\n";
    }
};

template<typename type_t>
auto create()
{
    // optional : if you only want to be able to create instances of A or B
    // static_assert(std::is_same_v<A, type_t> || std::is_same_v<B, type_t>);

    type_t object{};
    return object;
}

int main()
{
    auto a = create<A>();
    auto b = create<B>();

    a.hi();
    b.boo();

    return 0;
}
```